# Switch cameras in rooted device (between front and back)

Tags: root-access, camera, front-camera

My back camera has broken although the front camera is still working.

Certain applications, such as WhatsApp web, only let you use the back camera to read the QR code. Is there a way to switch cameras by editing a certain file in Root Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but its **Extremely** dangerous.

I highly recommend not doing this as its neither for your device and the risks are **too** high.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1699299

---

As for WhatsApp Web, it allows you to use your computer for WhatsApp conversations.

The draw back is that both your Android and your browser needs to be connected to Internet.

And the only advantage is that you get a keyboard which makes it really easier to type as well as a Big screen

Again there's an easy workaround.

Apps like [WiFi Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.volosyukivan&hl=en) allows you to type in your Android device through a computer browser.

And Apps like [droid VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc&hl=en) Allows you to remote control your android within your computer! Including watching your screen.

---

As for the other apps, you cant do much. Later so sooner you must change your broken phone..

Kudos

I hope my answer helps...
It requires a lot of hardwork to write a good answer. A thumbsup is always appreciated.

Comment: note that I don't think it's dangerous... you're just modifying a configuration file, and it will never brick your phone. You can always revert it back easily...

Answer (score 0):

I am using RED MI2.
My rear camera is not working. I needed to use front camera for QR Code scan, after attempting of so many `.apk` files,  I was not able to use front camera.

Last attempt I thought is to remove rear camera *physcially* and then try.

Result: It works. I can scan QR code with *Front Camera*

[Source: you tube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sex4yUcfnBk&noredirect=1)